# python - performance difference

Tags: python, performance

Following is my function definition

```
def func_a():
    return 1

def func_b(val1):
    return val1*2
```

And this is one way of calling the function:

```
count = 0
while count < 10000000:    
    val2 = func_b(func_a())
    count += 1
```

time taken for above is:

```
real    0m5.003s
user    0m4.989s
sys 0m0.012s
```

For the below usage with the same function definition:

```
count = 0
while count < 10000000:    
    ret1 = func_a()
    val2 = func_b(ret1)
    count += 1
```

the time taken is

```
real    0m5.502s
user    0m5.414s
sys 0m0.010s
```

I did about 10 runs each and the real time difference between the two was always ~300-500 ms.

Whereas the sys time was usually only about ~1-2 ms different. (max of about 10 ms).

The application I work with deals with about 60-90k transactions with sub millisecond performance, so this is kind of big for me. Why is there this much difference between the two invocations?

EDIT NOTE: The below answer is not much relevant now after the question revamp, please see the question edit for the original question.

Answer (score 5):

> From readability perspective (and code maintenance ?) I guess the
>   first one is better?

Actually the second one is better, especially if you are not using the return value of `function_a` anywhere else. Otherwise, the first line will create a name that may cause a namespace clash. Consider this:

```
foo = 42

# many many lines of code later

foo = function_a()
result = function_b(foo)

print foo # oops!
```

> Is the second one better from memory perspective

The cost is insignificant.

> Which of the two is better in terms of
>   performance?

There is no performance benefit that you can get from one approach or the other that would create any practical impact in your application.

Comment: >>Which of the two is better in terms of performance?

There is no performance benefit that you can get from one approach or the other that would create any practical impact in your application. <<  the difference is of the order of ~100ms and that is big number for applications dealing with sub ms numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. There might be an incredibly minor speed advantage due to skipping a few loads and stores without the intermediate variable, and using the variable might extend the lifetime of a temporary a bit, slightly affecting memory usage patterns, but the difference isn't even worth considering. In different situations, one might be more readable than the other. Try to avoid ultra-long lines, and if you're going to pull pieces out of an expression for readability, try to pick meaningful pieces.

Answer (score -1):

The disadvantage of the former approach is that you generate intermediate variables that should never be used again, and you or somebody else might accidentally write one of them (that is, later use "val1" instead of "val2"). Intermediate values are not a serious issue, but they do occasionally cause programming mistakes.

The latter approach may be a little less readable. It looks a lot better in an object oriented context:

```
val2 = function_a().function_b()
```

Comment: This is not doing the same thing; this is attempting to call the `function_b` method of the return value of `function_a`, and then assign the result of that call to `val2`.

Comment: Yes, and if the proper object oriented methods are defined, it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Except the question isn't about "object oriented methods" (whatever that means).

Comment: Please don't comment on answers if you don't understand them. (Besides to ask for clarification or help.)